# Need chapter and heading center alignment without changing font size in memoir

Tags: memoir

Well, I just need to center the chapter and headings BUT I need to keep the formatting, I have used a `\titlesec` solution from another question and it ended up messing with the font size though.

I really appreciate some guidance...

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany,showtrims,a5paper]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % Define a fonte garamond
\usepackage{leading} %Define espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage{titlesec} %Centralizar Cap e cabeçalho

\setulmarginsandblock{0,8in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem vertical maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem vertical maior

\setlrmarginsandblock{0,5in}{0,5in}{*} %Define margem horizontal maior
\checkandfixthelayout %Define margem horizontal maior

\makeevenfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{}

\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeevenfoot{chapter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeevenhead{chapter}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{chapter}{}{}{}

\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\bfseries\huge} %Formata Nº título de Cap
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\small} %Formata "Capítulo X"
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge} %Formata Título de Cap

\begin{document} 
    \leading{14,5pt}

    \chapter*{Dedicatória}
        \input{1dedicatoria}
        \newpage

    \chapter*{Agradecimentos}
        \input{2agradecimentos}

    \tableofcontents*

    \chapter*{Síntese}
        \input{3sintese}

    \chapter*{Apresentação}
        \input{4apresentacao}

    \chapter{Preparação}
        \input{5preparacao}
    ...
    \chapter*{Conclusão}
        \input{26conclusao}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "I just need to center the chapter and headings". Which headings? Those of section-level or subsection-level headers? Please clarify.

Comment: And your example does not use anything related to `titlesec`, all of it `memoir` code

Comment: I need to align the "Chapter 1 + Name of the Chapter".
Yes, I removed the titlesec, because it was of no use.